# How to change the order of the product list in cart_products in TYPO3 11?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I would like to create links that let the user sort the product list in cart_products ascending and descending.

For this I created a Fluid-link in `Grid.html` of [cart_products](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/cart_products) that passes an argument for sorting to the controller:

```xml
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{sorting:'up'}">Sorting up</f:link.action>
```

The method `listAction()` in `ProductController.php` gets the argument with:

```php
if ($this->request->hasArgument('sorting')) {
    $sorting = $this->request->getArgument('sorting');
}
```

With this if-statement I control what is happening based on the given argument:

```php
if ($sorting === "up") {
    // Get all products sorted ascending
} elseif ($sorting === "down"){
    // Get all products sorted decending
}
```

The products are received with the following command (original):

```php
$products = $this->productRepository->findDemanded($demand);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/main/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html) says that the following function does the sorting:

```php
$query->setOrderings(
    [
        'organization.name' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
        'title' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
    ]
);
```

I would like to know how to combine the both parts to receive the products ordered as wished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view helper to directly use sorting argument

```
<f:link.action action="listSorted" arguments="{sorting:'asc'}">Sorting up</f:link.action>
```

Add your own controller action (extending class ProductController)

```
<?php

    // ...
    public function listSortedAction(int $currentPage = 1): void
    {
    $demand = $this->createDemandObjectFromSettings($this->settings);
    
    // ...
    // Code from cart_products/Classes/Controller/ProductController.php listAction()
    // ...
    // instead of $products = $this->productRepository->findDemanded($demand);
    if ($this->request->hasArgument('sorting')) {
        $sorting = $this->request->getArgument('sorting');
        $products = $this->productRepository->findDemandedSorted($demand,$sorting);
    }
    //...

?>
```

Then add you own repository function (extending class ProductRepository)

```
<?php

    public function findDemandedSorted(ProductDemand $demand, $sortOrder)
    {

    $query = $this->createQuery();

    // ...
    // Code from cart_products/Classes/Domain/Repository/Product/ProductRepository.php findDemanded(ProductDemand $demand)
    // ...

    // instead of
    // if ($orderings = $this->createOrderingsFromDemand($demand)) {
    //     $query->setOrderings($orderings);
    // }
    $query->setOrderings($sortOrder);

    return $query->execute();
}
```